# Изменение contentSize UIScrollView динамически

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Привет!

Дело такое: при открытии вьюшки я загружаю данные с сервера. И в зависимости от количества полученных данных я пытаюсь изменить contentSize у scrollView. Autolayout включен. К тому же, я не могу прописать размеры contentSize заранее в:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 3000);
}
```

Пробовал [сделать по этой инструкции](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html), но так тоже не работает

Comment: Выключайте Autolayout во всех случаях работы с динамически расширяемыми областями, в данном случае ScrollView.

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ : http://hashcode.ru/questions/323766/ios7-xcode-autolayout

Вам так же надо поступить. Просто объявить константу высоты и изменять ее. Так как то, что вы пытаетесь сделать "рубится" как раз автолауоутом.

Comment: А самый простой ответ: - А что вам мешает добавить UITextView и помещать туда? Там автоматом все сделается.

Comment: а как с выключенным autolayout'ом работать с другим разрешением, например 3.5-дюйма? А то на 4-4с айфоне у меня таббар уходит за пределы экрана

Comment: Дык... Почитай мой ответ! я ссылку выше дал. Ненадо ничего отключать! Но и думать и делать надо по другому. Автолауоут это визуальная штука, которая (практически) конфигурируется в InterfaceBuilder, в коде ею управлять почти нельзя (ну точнее ооочень сложно).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а вьюшку в DrawRect ом рисуете?если так то
загружайте данные, перед тем как построить вьюшку вызывайте метод sizeThatFits: в котором вы построете вьюху по тем данным которые загрузили но не отображайте ее, передайте этот размер scrollView и потом стройте вашу вьюшку